# FTP Image from Base64 with PHP

Tags: php, ftp, base64

I have an image (in Base64) that I need to FTP to a remote server using PHP.  How can I accomplish this?

This is my latest attempt...

```
// Image
$handle = fopen('data://image/jpeg;base64,'.$base64, 'r');

// Setup and login
$creds = array(
    'server' => '*****',
    'user' => '*****',
    'pass' => '*****'
);
$conn = ftp_connect($creds['server']);
$loginResult = ftp_login($conn, $creds['user'], $creds['pass']); 

// Upload 
ftp_fput($conn, '/path/to/file.jpg', $handle, FTP_ASCII);

// Cleanup
ftp_close($conn);
fclose($handle);
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: With a little bit of research: [`base64_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) | [php.net/FTP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php)

Comment: I've already tried a number of variations, but all I get is what appears to be a very distorted image of various colors and shapes... not the image I input.  The size of the file seems correct, but it looks corrupted.  I will update my question with my most recent attempt.  I must be missing something.

Comment: Couple of issues:  Is this a cut-down version of your code? `fopen` returns a resource handle - that's all (not the file itself) and I'm fairly certain you can't fopen a data uri like that.  where is the `$base64` data coming?  There's no need for it to be base64 encoded for FTP transport - it should be decoded and sent in binary mode.

Comment: (given that the `$base64` variable doesn't already include the uri scheme can I also assume that you have encoded the image in the first place? - in which case this part of the solution probably isn't needed)

Comment: Yes, this is a condensed version for testing.  `$base64` is already encoded and is being pulled from our database (I'm not a fan of saving images in this manner, but don't have a choice in this current setup).

Comment: OMG! Thank you!  The existing code works perfectly by just switching `FTP_ASCII` to `FTP_BINARY`.  Please post as an answer so I can accept it. :)

Comment: Well I feel a little bit guilty - I've learnt something new, it turns out you can `fopen` a data URI but I'll accept the points :P - I was looking for a way to send raw data but apparently there isn't a function for that.

Comment: Hah, no worries.  I completely disregarded the whole ascii/binary thing until you mentioned it.  Lightbulb... on!  Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary files should be transferred in binary mode...

```
ftp_fput($conn, '/path/to/file.jpg', $handle, FTP_BINARY);
```